# How to make your app create a shortcut in the startup folder on install Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2022, publish

I am struggling to find guides or explanations online on how to make a shortcut for my app to appear in the startup folder upon the installation of the app.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and the app is written in C#.

Comment: That would be a feature of the ["Installer Project"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022).

Comment: ^^ Outside the "on-board" techs from MS (one-click, setup project, ...), there are also independed packaging / setup creator solutions. All of which provide this as a feature _outside_ of your application.

Comment: Hi, if my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022) comes with this function, when you After following a normal procedure to create a Setup Project, you can put the program's shortcut into the startup folder through the following methods:

1. Right-click File System on Target Machine => Add Special Folder => User’s Startup Folder

   [image]
2. Right-click your primary output in the Application Folder, click Create Shortcut to Primary..., create a shortcut to the primary output and pull the shortcut into User’s Startup Folder

   [image]
3. After building the project, open the installer installer and remember to click Install this program for everyone

   [image]
4. After the installation is complete, open the Startup folder and you will find the shortcut to the program inside.

   [image]

If you already know how to create setup projects, this will go smoothly. If you have any questions, please let me know.